# Vue.js convert all inputs to a v-model

Tags: vue.js

I just want to know if what i'm doing is correct.
The goal

here is to convert all input fields in a v-model.

Right now im using jQuery to do that, and is working well.

Is there any way to do it with pure vue.js?

**Some considerations:**

- I don't want to use `v-model` or any vue attribute on the html like `ref="foo"`.
- The data must be in and object and I don't want to predefine.

Thanks

```js
const vueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: {
    dataForm: {}
  },
  created() {
    $("input").each(function(){
      var $input_name = 'dataForm.' + $(this).attr('name');
      $(this).attr('v-model',  $input_name);
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vue-app">
  <div class="">
    First Nane : {{ dataForm.firstName }}
  </div>
  <div class="">
    Last Name : {{ dataForm.lastName }}
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use v-model to begin with? Why use jQuery to replace anything?

Comment: You should never mix jQuery and Vue. jQuery manipulates the actual DOM, Vue has a virtual DOM it updates and then makes sure the actual DOM imitates.

Comment: So basically if you use jQuery at all you're doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Are you asking how to simulate `v-model` programmatically? If so, why?

Comment: We have a lot of forms, with an infinite number of input fields, we do not want to have to edit all that HTML and we think that the best way is just wrapping them in a #app.

Comment: Maybe a separate script could be triggered on document ready that uses jQuery to add v-model to all inputs? Then load up your Vue app after that finishes?